Juggling Solo Projects and Leadership: A Senior Developer's Struggle
I want to start by explaining my situation: I’m the sole person managing and executing several projects at my company. By "sole person," I mean I’m the only software engineer, the only one performing QA, and the one meeting with clients to discuss and organize next steps. I handle everything end-to-end in terms of software.
Recently, I was promoted. While this is an exciting step, it has come with significant additional responsibilities. Now, on top of my existing duties, I am leading a team of junior developers on a critical project. These juniors have very limited experience with the type of work we do here; one of them has just 7-8 months of experience. This makes the task of leading them quite challenging, as I am the only senior on the team.
I am responsible for determining the architecture, distributing tasks, reviewing their work, and essentially guiding them through every step. They’re still learning, and that’s perfectly fine—they’re juniors, after all. However, it has slowed progress on this project.
To complicate matters, I’m unable to contribute directly to coding for this project because my "solo" responsibilities on other projects already take up all my time. Recently, I was reprimanded by the company’s top boss for the perceived slow pace of the work. I tried to explain the challenges, particularly the team's inexperience, but I’m not sure my explanation landed well. Now I’m unsure how to proceed.

A purely hypothetical question: exactly how screwed would your employer be if you quit tomorrow?

@PhilipKendall You know what they say – there are no irreplaceable people.

When you explained to your manager that it is impossible for one person to be responsible for everything you perceive yourself to be responsible for, what was their response?

"I’m the only software engineer" "on top of my existing duties, I am leading a team of junior developers" Did the extra developers not exist before you do you just mean they lack some formal/informal features to be deemed "proper" software engineers?

@MisterMiyagi I read it as: OP is the sole developer in a handful of projects, but in another project they lead a bunch of (junior) software developers, so the company has other devs, but not assigned to or familiar with those specific projects OP is responsible for.

Present your manager with different options about your priorities
The problem with your current approach is that you have waited for the project to noticeably slow down and being asked before communicating the challenge.
With hindsight what you should have done is to address the problem by yourself and present your boss with different options. Luckily the problem is still there, so you can still do that now:
Describe what needs to be done, both in term of on-boarding and solving the problem and determine reasonable options on how to proceed.
And the options could look something like this:
1.) You can focus fully on on-boarding your team, which would mean you would maybe get very little done for the next X month, but then you have a team which can work on the problem with a decent pace.
2.) You can focus on delivering the feature and accept that your team is partially idle since there is nobody to onboard it.
3.) You can do a compromise somewhere between 1 and 2
Solutions might also involve the manager agreeing to changing the current setup like:
4.) Your manager provides outside help to support with some of the on-boarding while you focus on clarifying the architecture.
5.) You trade 2 of the junior members for 1 senior member with another team.
This way you play the ball back to the manager, explaining them that they cannot have everything and still give them viable alternatives to choose between according to their priorities.
Try to put yourself in your managers shoes and think about what option makes sense for them to pick, given their current constraints. Don't go overboard with options and only include options that make sense for them to pick and give a recommended option.

I'd be careful with how to word  1) - the current way it is phrased make sit a promise that after X amount of time investment speed will be at a satisfying level. This might work, but since those are junior devs, this is not guaranteed, as they not only need an onboarding in the domain area, but also need to grow into somewhat experienced devs that can make their own decisions at least on the smaller level with a reliable level of getting those decisions right. For some juniors it takes quite long to reach that point, others indeed are there in no-time.

Have a discussion with your bosses about the "mythical man-month."
Buy them the book if you need to.  Reading it yourself would also help.

You had a work load based on specific projects
You now have an additional project, resourced with new resources that require your attention.

You can't accomplish both 1 and 2 with the same hours in a week.  You cannot drive schedule with just more resources.  Your company is trying to do too much.

So basically the solution you are proposing is to tell them that they are wrong and lecture them on how to do management?

@Helena - Sometimes, yes. Telling Management you cannot be in two places at the same time is sometimes necessary.

@Helena, it's called managing up.

@Helena: Not they are wrong. The input data they either receive or assume is wrong, or at least misleading.

@Helena, yes, exactly that! The reality is that many self-designated managers don't know how to manage, let alone manage software development.

@Helena it's not even on how to do management, but on how the craft they are managing works. For some problems more people means automatically more output in a linear way,for others it doesn't and many fall in-between "negative benefit when adding people" and "exponential benefit when adding people". This would just be readjustment feedback - if done right.  (I do agree that just throwing the book at them would be confrontational though; i.e. the delivery of the feedback needs some work beyond this answer).

Taking a leadership position usually does mean you need to spend time leading and that you are going to do less individual work. It means thinking of the team as one of your development tools, and recognizing that guiding the team is productive work, though at a higher level.
Productivity may suffer during the period when you are getting the team trained up to an adequate level, though hopefully once they are brought up to speed the group's overall productivity will improve.
Management should understand that and accept it. If you aren't sure they fo, talk to them about it and make sure they understand that training and supervision consumes resources so your own output will suffer until the new folks are fully up to speed.
It certainly is possible to add people to a project and hand off tasks to them and achieve a net gain, if you can invest the time in training and communication and if the task can be divided into smaller, preferably isolated, chunks. The "mythical man month" problem kicks in when the problem cannot be partitioned, or when the onboarding time and resources are not granted.
Of course, if management thinks you can squeeze it into your existing schedule, that's a challenge. In that case, all you can do is make sure that they have given you clear priorities and agree that items of lower priority may need to be deferred to make sure the higher priorities get addressed. In that case, getting clear agreement on what the priorities are is essential.
Remember that the goal here is to eventually take load off you, freeing you to work on the more exciting parts of the project.
